# Loop through object functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

`dir(object)` returns a list of object attributes and functions. How can I iterate over all callable functions and get the output of the functions? (ASSUMING NO FUNCTION ARGS)

```
for a in dir(obj) if not a.startswith('__') and callable(getattr(obj,a)):
    response = obj.a()
```

This does not work as python is treating a as the attribute name. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This will throw a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use getattr to actually get the callable and then call it ...

do this

```
fn = getattr(obj,a)
fn()
```

not this

```
obj.a()
```

of coarse you are not checking if the callable has any required arguments or anything like that ... im not sure what you are actually trying to accomplish... but im skeptical that this is the right technique

additionally you need one more `)` on this line  `callable(getattr(obj,a):`

Comment: I have an object. It is a post request werkzeug object. I want to iterate over all of the properties. I think all of the functions do not take arguments and just return values, such as obj.get_stream_data()

Comment: There are just many attributes and functions. I know how to access all of the attributes however the callables I dont know how to access once they have been aliased into a variable such as the for a in ... once the callable is referred to as `a` I dont know how to execute it anymore. To make matters worse I am accessing my request object as a child of another object.

Comment: how does this not address your question? or does this address your question?

Comment: I will be right back with either more questions, clarification or check marks! Thanks for helping. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Everyone hates this question. I have tried to rewrite it. Although I get that this is not a normal practice but I would think in some circumstances you may want to iterate through functions and get the output. Is there another way I should word this to make it less offensive?